# jQuery Autocomplete with WCF Data Services

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, wcf-data-services

I am planning to use jQuery Autocomplete (Not UI Autocomplete) plugin to fetch data from WCF Data Service. If I want to fetch all data, I can do that by directly firing query. However if I want to fetch data based on initial chars entered, I am not able to pass the value to the data service. My autocomplete code looks like

```
('#txtUsers')
    .autocomplete("http://localhost/DataService/DataService.svc/Users?$format=json", {
        width: 320,
        max: 10,
        minChars: 3,
        matchSubset: true,
        cacheLength: 100,
        extraParams: { "$filter" : "startswith(Name, '"+$(this).val()+"')" },
        formatItem: function(data, i, n, value, term) {
            return value;
        },
        parse: function(data) {
            return $.map(data.d, function(row, i) {
                return {
                    data: row,
                    value: row,
                    result: row
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

I tried to pass it with extraParams too but it holds blank value. How can I use autocomplete with WCF Data Services? I do not want ot add any QueryInterceptors as my data services is used by other apps also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The issue is resolved. I tweaked the extraParams option to

```
extraParams: {
    "$filter": function() { return "startswith(Name, '" + $('#txtUsers').val() + "')" }
}
```

Hopefully it could be beneficial for others.